# Change group permissions on file using os.chmod

Tags: python, file-permissions, macos-big-sur, python-3.9

I am using Python 3.9.1 in MacOS Big Sur 11.1 and using os.chmod to change file permissions. The user permission is always change successfully but never for group or others. I'm wondering if this might be a bug but I don't have an earlier MacOS platform to try it on, it failed on Python 3.8 hence the upgrade. Hopefully this issue will be user error!

```
os.chmod(file, stat.S_IRUSR|stat.S_IWUSR|stat.S_IRGRP|stat.S_IWGRP)
```

It doesn't work using octal either.

```
os.chmod(file, 0o640)
```

Comment: Are you able to change the permissions for the same file using the `chmod` shell command?

Comment: the permissions you wrote in the two examples differ. What _is_ your current file permission, what permission you actually intend to get, and what is the result you have?

Comment: Thanks, that's an excellent question @chepner . That's weird, perhaps it's a Google Drive thing as I assumed that being the file owner I'd have been able to change the group bit, but seemingly not. It's a shared drive so perhaps I need to take my work out of that environment, it's handy for working from home though.